# ExpressionEngine: Channel Entry Issues (Mobile ONLY)

Tags: mobile, expressionengine, channel

My website has 2 pages where a series of channel entries are listed. The 1st page list blog entries in an archive while the 2nd page list projects.

On a desktop, all entries appear without error; however on a mobile device using Safari, Chrome, Firefox, etc... these two pages won't load properly when more than 4 entries are listed. As an example, Chrome will display the "Aw Snap" message.

The page specifically breaks down when the following code fires:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel="projects" dynamic="no"}
<li>
   <a href="{url_title_path='projects/'}">
      <img src="{projects_box}" alt="">
      <h3>{projects_name}<span><br>{projects_city}</span></h3>
   </a>
</li>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Pagination is an option but each subsequent page would need to be limited to 4 entries which ultimately defeats the point of the blog archive and projects page.

You can view the project page/code [here](http://www.themediaplanners.com/projects).

I appreciate any feedback / code suggestions on how to fix the problem.

Comment: I think "Aw Snap" errors are generally not about code.  They are about the browser, the network, server error... Should not be different from desktop to mobile.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try to add these parameters to channel entries?

```
cache="yes" refresh="600" disable="categories|category_field|member_data|pagination"
```